# How do you catch a mysqli_connect() Unknown Server error?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have read many posts regarding the mysqli_connect() (HY000/2005) errors.  I am getting these errors from scripts that worked a week ago.  It appears, after looking at the ip trace for the database, that the connection trace is timing out along the route.  The data I am downloading is not extensive, certainly less then 2 MB.  When the error occurs I can refresh the page and the data shows up as expected.  So -- can I catch the error and refresh the script while the page is being posted?  If so, what is the best way of implementing this approach?

Thanks for your assistance!

S

Comment: You're not using the old try and catch method to receive mysqli errors, it's the same as the old mysql method: mysqli_connect() or mysqli_error(); mysqli_query() or mysqli_error(); etc.

Comment: I do test for a connection.  The tests are successful but I get the mysqli_connect() error.  One time a page will connect with no trouble, the next time, maybe a few seconds later, I will get the error.  A refresh fixes the problem.  Can I refresh a script programmatically without refreshing the entire page?

Comment: You need to figure out why connections aren't happening to the mysql server. It's not a fix to simply attempt connecting again or "refreshing" the page. Ultimately there is something that's causing your mysql connections to not happen some times. Once you resolve that you should be fine.

Comment: I understand the problem -- it is an Internet backbone issue, which is outside of my control.  My objective is to shield the user from these types of errors.

Comment: How were you able to determine it's an internet backbone issue? I've been a sysadmin for years and that seems like an odd thing to assume.

Comment: Actually it is not.  In fact a system administrator put me onto the potential of the problem.  To confirm I did a lot of troubleshooting.  First, the code was working without incident one day and the next it was not.  My initial thought was that the site was hacked.  I reviewed the code and found no evidence of hacking.  I then checked the performance of the code connecting on a local development machine and had no problem.  The connection was made immediately and the code responded as expected.

Comment: (cont'd) I then checked the execution of the query using the database control panel on the site itself.  Again, the query code executed properly and quickly.  The only remaining factor was the Internet itself.  For that I reviewed the IP Trace and used the Firefox development tools to check the responsiveness of the Internet.  I found large delays in both the IP Trace and in the network responsiveness shown in the Firefox tools.

Comment: BTW, what was almost a full minute of waiting is now only a few milliseconds -- no code change.

Comment: Are you connecting directly to an IP or to a hostname which would in turn query a dns server first? Ultimately I just don't believe this a problem you should have to program to avoid - this is something that a network engineer should be looking into and correcting as it's probably effecting more than just you. Usually DB servers are in close physical proximity to the web servers that interact with them and at most are just different subnets and/or different firewalls, is that not in your case?

Comment: I did use an IP address to connect.  And, I agree with you that network engineers should have known.  I also don't think it was only me that was affected.  That is why I want to catch the error and refresh the page.  The issue is not the DB connection per se, it is the length of time it takes to get the data across the Internet backbone.  As for the subnet, I am using a hosted server so I can't give you any insight into how the network is structured. I can only provide info on my troubleshooting efforts, which included talking to the service provider.